# I have an issue in Restful API by Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, api, rest

I want to make Rest API by Laravel ,
and i'm in order to create fake data 
and i have this problem after migration process , in data base seeding process ,,

```
php artisan migrate:fresh
```

when i hit this command in terminal , every thing is fine and migrate successfully

but the issue is here when i hit this command

```
php artisan db:seed
```

and there is there error

```
Carbon\Exceptions\InvalidFormatException 

  Could not parse '1': DateTime::__construct(): Failed to parse time string (1) at position 0 (1): Unexpected character

  at vendor/nesbot/carbon/src/Carbon/Traits/Creator.php:188
    184|         } catch (Exception $exception) {
    185|             $date = @static::now($tz)->change($time);
    186| 
    187|             if (!$date) {
  > 188|                 throw new InvalidFormatException("Could not parse '$time': ".$exception- 
    getMessage(), 0, $exception);
    189|             }
    190| 
    191|             return $date;
    192|         }

  1   [internal]:0
      Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\FactoryBuilder::Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\{closure}()

      +1 vendor frames 
  3   [internal]:0
      Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\FactoryBuilder::Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\{closure}()
```

and i will take photo for details

[here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kWdC6.png)

**UPDATE::**

after changing 'email_verified_at' => $faker->randomElement to 'email_verified_at' => $faker->dateTime

got this error

```
Illuminate\Database\QueryException 

  SQLSTATE[22003]: Numeric value out of range: 1264 Out of range value for column 'email_verified_at' at row 1 (SQL: insert into `users` (`first_name`, `last_name`, `email`, `email_verified_at`, `mobile`, `mobile_verified_at`, `password`, `remember_token`, `updated_at`, `created_at`) values (Salvador, Reynolds, smith.jarred@example.org, 1973-06-05 00:00:00, 1-489-345-8354 x338, 1973-06-02, $2y$10$92IXUNpkjO0rOQ5byMi.Ye4oKoEa3Ro9llC/.og/at2.uheWG/igi, OBAqyXgPHJ, 2020-05-17 01:11:56, 2020-05-17 01:11:56))

  at vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php:671
    667|         // If an exception occurs when attempting to run a query, we'll format the error
    668|         // message to include the bindings with SQL, which will make this exception a
    669|         // lot more helpful to the developer instead of just the database's errors.
    670|         catch (Exception $e) {
  > 671|             throw new QueryException(
    672|                 $query, $this->prepareBindings($bindings), $e
    673|             );
    674|         }
    675| 

      +16 vendor frames 
  17  database/seeds/DatabaseSeeder.php:15
      Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\FactoryBuilder::create()
```

Comment: are you passing a date or datetime while seeding factory ?

Comment: also show your factory code how you have made it ?

Comment: 'first_name' => $faker->firstname,
        'last_name' => $faker->lastname,

        'email' => $faker->unique()->safeEmail,
        'email_verified_at' => $faker->randomElement([false , true]),

        'mobile' => $faker->phoneNumber,
        'mobile_verified_at' => $faker->randomElement([true , false]),

        'password' => '$2y$10$92IXUNpkjO0rOQ5byMi.Ye4oKoEa3Ro9llC/.og/at2.uheWG/igi', // password
        'remember_token' => Str::random(10),

Comment: `email_verified_at` here you need to pass a date, simply `now()` and see affect.

Comment: hx for ur answer , i used this line 'email_verified_at' => $faker->dateTime but i have anew error >>>>>> Illuminate\Database\QueryException SQLSTATE[22003]: Numeric value out of range: 1264 Out of range value for column 'email_verified_at' at row 1 (SQL: insert into users (first_name, last_name, email, email_verified_at, mobile, mobile_verified_at, password, remember_token, updated_at, created_at) values (Julia, Lubowitz, bfay@example.com, 1975

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using a boolean value on `email_verified_at` which is a Datetime type column. You can use `$faker->date` or other formats specified in Faker documentation https://github.com/fzaninotto/Faker#fakerproviderdatetime.

Also to use booleans you can write `$faker->boolean` instead of `$faker->randomElement([false, true])` as you did.

Comment: tried to use $faker->dateTime instead of $faker->randomElement but they show me new error <<<<<<< ErrorException 

  strtotime() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given

  at vendor/fzaninotto/faker/src/Faker/Provider/DateTime.php:25

Comment: try to add toString() function with $faker->dateTime

Comment: Line 27 should be `'email_verified_at' => $faker->date,`. No array parameters.

Comment: hx for ur answer , i used this line 'email_verified_at' => $faker->dateTime but i have anew error >>>>>> Illuminate\Database\QueryException SQLSTATE[22003]: Numeric value out of range: 1264 Out of range value for column 'email_verified_at' at row 1 (SQL: insert into users (first_name, last_name, email, email_verified_at, mobile, mobile_verified_at, password, remember_token, updated_at, created_at) values (Julia, Lubowitz, bfay@example.com, 1975

Comment: The error message was cut before I could seed what value was being inserted in `email_verified_at` field. What was the value used in the SQL statement? I belive you are using a MySQL database, if so, check if the column type is set to `timestamp` or `datetime`. If not specify what database you use.

Answer (score 0):

As others mentioned, email_verified_at is a datetime type column. I always use  `'email_verified_at' => $faker->dateTime` rather than `$faker->date`.

Comment: thx for ur answer , i used this line 'email_verified_at' => $faker->dateTime but i have anew error >>>>>>
 Illuminate\Database\QueryException 

  SQLSTATE[22003]: Numeric value out of range: 1264 Out of range value for column 'email_verified_at' at row 1 (SQL: insert into `users` (`first_name`, `last_name`, `email`, `email_verified_at`, `mobile`, `mobile_verified_at`, `password`, `remember_token`, `updated_at`, `created_at`) values (Julia, Lubowitz, bfay@example.com, 1975-07-17

Answer (score 0):

**SOLVED**

thx for every one that reply me ,,

i solved it by changing data type to dateTime in USER table

Comment: Your original issue was using boolean on a date field. Then your column type was not set correctly. Both problems were answered here by other users. I believe you did not came to this conclusion by yourself so you should credit the other. Also, marking your question as SOLVED by selecting the correct answer help others with the same problem in the future.